# Using 持っていく with people

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to use 持{も}っていく with people?  Or is another verb used for taking people to places? For example: 毎日学校に妹を持っていく

Comment: I guess you can say 毎日学校に妹を持っていく if you like, but it sounds pejorative (you look treating your sister like a thing rather than a living human being.) We usually say 毎日学校に妹を連（つ）れていく.

Comment: 連れていくis the best choice in this situation..

Comment: If 連れて行く is only used for people of lower status which words apply to people of equal and of higher status?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot 持っていく to mean bringing someone somewhere. It's only used when talking about objects, hence the literal meaning "hold and go".

If you want to say "to take someone somewhere", you should either some form of 連れる{つれる}, like 連れていく, or 送る. Keep in mind though that 連れていく is only for bringing people of lower status.

> 毎日学校に妹を連れていく

Comment: < 連れていく is only for bringing people of lower status.>

I don't think so. Don't you say 「両親を(海外旅行に, say) 連れていく」?

Comment: Out if curiosity, could you use it if you were literally carrying someone away?

Comment: If 連れて行く is only used for people of lower status which words apply to people of equal and of higher status?

Comment: @eltonjohn practically all dictionaries I've found translate it as something like "to take someone (of lower status) along", and after looking at many sentences that seems to be the case. It's probably more complicated than that, like anyone of lower status *or* anyone in your social circle, but then it should be a separate question and explanation.

Comment: Alright. I am hoping (but not necessarily expecting) you can post a separate question.

Comment: @Eric: If you mean by "carrying someone away" taking someone on contrary to his/her free will, you can say 連行する.

Comment: "carry someone away" >> I'd say 「連れ去る」。。。　（「連行する」って、警察みたい。。。）」

Comment: @eltonjohn I posted a question about it [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25353/)

Comment: @Choko: <「連行する」って、警察みたい> Sure, it is. Why not? "Carrying away" has a negative connotation, I think.

Comment: @Rudy the Reindeer: You may want to have a look at this -> http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25353/ .

Comment: @eltonjohn じゃ、警察以外の人（誘拐犯など）が小さな子どもをcarry awayする場合も意味はnegativeですが、「連行する」が使える？

Comment: @Choko: I would say 誘拐する or 拉致する in those cases. 連れ去る would be fine, but I prefer more straightforward expressions. 連行する for actions by non "authoritative" subjects may sound unnatural, but not ridiculous. E.g., 北朝鮮工作員達は無辜の日本人を「招待」と称して恫喝して連行した 。

Comment: @eltonjohn Oh wow, thank you! The link you posted was very helpful to me!

Comment: 「幼女が何者かに carry away されて遺体で発見された。」の場合はどうするんですか。犯人が捕まっていなくて、目撃者もいなかったら、拉致されたか誘拐されたか、わからないですよね？